# What is/are the effect(s) of altering the Tris concentration on polyacrylamide gels?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins, methods, sds-page

Why do we use two different concentrations of Tris (*i.e.* 1.5M Tris in resolving gel and 1.0M Tris in stacking gel)? For the gel to run properly there needs to be a different pH, but that can be done with with same Tris concentration and altering the HCl concentration.